# Exception: Unable to communicate with RAS

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I get this exception while tinkering with Google Play Game Services - real time multiplayer. I was trying to create a room for automatch and this happen. This is strange because I have successfully created a multiplayer room many times before. I don't know what it is and how to avoid this?

```
07-30 14:48:06.103    1063-1063/com.google.android.gms E/RoomServiceClientStateMachine﹕ Unable to communicate with RAS
    android.os.RemoteException: Service disconnected
            at ffz.onServiceDisconnected(SourceFile:79)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1115)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1129)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 14:48:06.103      636-660/system_process W/DropBoxManagerService﹕ Dropping: SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE (1161 > 0 bytes)
07-30 14:48:06.113    1063-1063/com.google.android.gms I/RoomServiceClientStateMachine﹕ Unable to kill RAS (may already be dead)
    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
            at ecm.a(SourceFile:388)
            at ffv.b(SourceFile:111)
            at ffz.onServiceDisconnected(SourceFile:79)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1115)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1129)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 14:48:06.113      636-965/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.google.android.gms.room (pid 12294) has died.
07-30 14:48:06.143      180-180/? D/Zygote﹕ Process 12294 terminated by signal (11)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code around where this exception is occurring? Also, please provide the steps for reproducing the error.

Comment: I got this problem when sending null message with the sendReliableMessage method